# How to create post URL for python-requests from Charles

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I think I'm way over my head and my question might be too generic, but hopefully someone can point me to the right direction.

I'm trying to reverse engineer the URL used in our web based monitoring app ([WhatsUpGold](http://www.whatsupgold.com/)) to disable the monitoring for a host via a python script. I've used Charles to show me the post URL and data, but I can't get it to work with `python-requests` (due to my lack of python and web knowledge).

This is the data being posted to the server when you click the 'disable' button, which is double urlencoded (I've changed user, IP and host):

```
__DIALOG_OUT_PARAM.MB_ANSWER=DISABLE_%3A1&__DIALOGRESULT=-1&__DIALOGCLOSING=DlgM
essageBox.asp&__FORMID=%7BB1F8B816-52D1-463E-8669-44C01E276FC5%7D&DlgDevicePrope
rtiesActiveMonitors.oListActiveMonitors=1&_isDirty=true&DlgDevicePropertiesActiv
eMonitors.DIALOGRETURNURL=%2FNmConsole%2FDeviceManagement%2FDlgDeviceProperties%
2FDlgDevicePropertiesSummary%2FDlgDevicePropertiesSummary.asp&DlgDevicePropertie
sActiveMonitors.SAVEDFORMSTATE=%253cSavedFormState%253e%253cFormVariables%253e%2
53coElement%2520sName%3D%2522ShowAspFormDialog.VISITEDFORM%2522%2520sValue%3D%25
22visited%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522_isDirty%2522%2520sValue%3D
%2522false%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary
.DIALOGRETURNURL%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522%2FNmConsole%2F%24Nm%2FCore%2FForm-AspFo
rms%2Finc%2FShowAspFormDialog.asp%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522Dlg
DevicePropertiesSummary.SAVEDFORMSTATE%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522%25253cSavedFormSt
ate%25253e%25253cFormVariables%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522__VIEW
STATE%252522%252520sValue%3D%252522%2525253cViewState%2F%2525253e%0D%0A%252522%2
F%25253e%25253c%2FFormVariables%25253e%25253cQueryStringVariables%2F%25253e%2525
3c%2FSavedFormState%25253e%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDeviceP
ropertiesSummary.VISITEDFORM%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522visited%2522%2F%253e%253coEl
ement%2520sName%3D%2522__VIEWSTATE%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522%25253cViewState%25253
e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sNote%252522%25
2520sValue%3D%252522This%252520device%252520was%252520cloned%252520from%252520th
e%252520device%252520%27server1%27%252520on%2525207%2F3%2F2013%25252010%3A51%3A0
5%252520AM.%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDeviceProper
tiesSummary.nDeviceID%252522%252520sValue%3D%2525222096%252522%2F%25253e%25253co
Element%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nBestStateID%252522%2525
20sValue%3D%2525224%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevi
cePropertiesSummary.sDeviceTypeName%252522%252520sValue%3D%252522RedHat%252522%2
F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sHostNam
e%252522%252520sValue%3D%252522server2%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sNa
me%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sNetworkAddress%252522%252520sValue%3D%25
252210.10.10.10%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePr
opertiesSummary.sDisplayName%252522%252520sValue%3D%252522server2%252522%2F%2525
3e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nWorstStateID%
252522%252520sValue%3D%2525224%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%25
2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nSelectedProperty%252522%252520sValue%3D%252522-1
%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary
.nDeviceTypeID%252522%252520sValue%3D%25252235%252522%2F%25253e%25253coElement%2
52520sName%3D%252522bWriteRights%252522%252520sValue%3D%2525221%252522%2F%25253e
%25253coElement%252520sName%3D%252522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sWebUserName%252
522%252520sValue%3D%252522user1%252522%2F%25253e%25253c%2FViewState%25253e%0D%0A
%2522%2F%253e%253c%2FFormVariables%253e%253cQueryStringVariables%2F%253e%253c%2F
SavedFormState%253e&DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.VISITEDFORM=visited&DlgDeviceProp
ertiesActiveMonitors.VISITEDFORM=visited&__VIEWSTATE=%253cViewState%253e%253coEl
ement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sNote%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522T
his%2520device%2520was%2520cloned%2520from%2520the%2520device%2520%27server1%27%
2520on%25207%2F3%2F2013%252010%3A51%3A05%2520AM.%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520s
Name%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors.nDeviceID%2522%2520sValue%3D%25222
096%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors
.bPollingOrder%2522%2520sValue%3D%25220%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2
522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nDeviceID%2522%2520sValue%3D%25222096%2522%2F%253e
%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nBestStateID%2522%2520
sValue%3D%25224%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSu
mmary.sDeviceTypeName%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522RedHat%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%25
20sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sHostName%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522serve
r2%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sNetwor
kAddress%2522%2520sValue%3D%252210.10.10.10%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%
3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sDisplayName%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522server2%25
22%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors.nSele
ctedProperty%2522%2520sValue%3D%25222%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%252
2DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nWorstStateID%2522%2520sValue%3D%25224%2522%2F%253e%
253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.nSelectedProperty%2522%
2520sValue%3D%2522-1%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropert
iesSummary.nDeviceTypeID%2522%2520sValue%3D%252235%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%252
0sName%3D%2522bWriteRights%2522%2520sValue%3D%25221%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%25
20sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors.sWebUserName%2522%2520sValue%3D
%2522user1%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesActiveM
onitors.nNewMonitorIDCounter%2522%2520sValue%3D%25221%2522%2F%253e%253coElement%
2520sName%3D%2522DlgDevicePropertiesSummary.sWebUserName%2522%2520sValue%3D%2522
user1%2522%2F%253e%253c%2FViewState%253e%0D%0A
```

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Referer:https://whatsup.mydomain.com/NmConsole/CoreNm/DlgMessageBox/DlgMessageBox.asp
Host:whatsup.mydomain.com
Connection:keep-alive
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

I tried posting it with the following code... and it doesn't fail, but it also does not post.

```
auth = 'username:password'

url = 'https://whatsup.mydomain.com/NmConsole/DeviceManagement/DlgDeviceProperties/DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors/DlgDevicePropertiesActiveMonitors.asp'

headers = {'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

payload = [code block above]

req = requests.post(url,payload,headers=headers,auth=auth)
```

I'm not expecting this to be a simple answer... but maybe some pointers of where to look.

Thanks,
Victor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do

```
req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers,auth=auth)
```

For me sending just payload "make noise" here, because you do not specific what you are sending.